# PlatformNotSupportedException throws when using Dapper with WP

Tags: c#, uwp, dapper

Executing a UWP application in `DEBUG` works perfectly.

Using exactly the same code compiled in `RELEASE` crashes with this error message

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 
    'Dynamic code generation is not supported on this platform.'
```

when executing this code (it's using `Dapper 1.5.1` and `System.Data.SQLite 1.0.109.2`)

```
using (var c = NewConnection())
{
    var sql = @"
        update settings
        set
            ""value"" = @SetDate
        where ""key"" = 'week_date'";
    c.Execute(sql, new { SetDate = date }); //<= throws PlatformNotSupportedException 
                                            // only on RELEASE not in DEBUG
}
```

The application is UWP configured as below. Furthermore, the faulting code is a `.NET Standard 2.0` `Class Library`

[image]

Why is it crashing on `RELEASE` only and how to fix it?

Comment: I think the error tells you everything you need to know, not sure you can get around that.

Comment: Have you selected the "Dynamic code generation" feature in the AppManifest?

Comment: Ever get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dapper is very deeply based on runtime IL generation, in ways that it would be basically impossible to change. Runtime IL generation is fundamentally not compatible with UWP.

There is no simple way of making this work.

So: to do this, you'd need to use something dapper-like-but-not-dapper, with one of two alternative implementations:

- *reflection*-based binding (relatively slow, depending on how much data access you're doing)
- *compile-time code-gen* of the missing pieces, presumably using some kind of roslyn analysis and partial class generation

Perhaps right now, the more pragamatic approach would be: don't use dapper in this case.

Comment: Ok, Isee, I'll envisage removing Dapper then. But why the App is running perfectly in `DEBUG` and not in `RELEASE`

Comment: @JiBéDoublevé presumably: debug builds *cheat*

Comment: @JiBéDoublevé had the same issue. Did you get dapper working with uwp ?